# Computer Boot/Installation Failure

Tags: installation, boot

I recently tried to insatll Kubuntu and it failed. It completely removed everything off of my HDD and there is no operating system. Everytime I try to install a Distro it fails during instillation. I got Ubuntu 13.04 to work but it required a reboot and after that it did not work. I tried to re-install Ubuntu but it failed. I have tried Ubuntu, Kubuntu, and Xubuntu and they all failed. With Kubuntu and Xubuntu I get an error saying, **"The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot"**. When I select try (distro) it loads up but the installation won't finish. I do not want to have to try the distro everytime I want to get on it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default partitioning of the installer?

If so, is your motherboard supports UEFI or BIOS and which one did you boot and installed as?

Try booting up with LiveCD.

open up terminal, learn how to chroot from internet. and configure your bootloader again with grub-install command, if gives any error, try commanding it in specific compts that you can find in google; like " grub-install --root-directory=/"

I'm  surprised that nothing boots up. Don't partition it yourself and try not to use LVM if you did in the last try.

Comment: I'm doing the delete all on disk and install (Distro) because I had stuff I wanted to remove and I do not want to get involved with screwing up the partioning. My motherboard supports UEFI and Legacy BIOS, but I booted up and installed as UEFI mode using a LiveUSB

Comment: By Distro, you mean Ubuntu right? I would suggest go with the default image. It doesn't really matter for first boot and you can always switch environments.

Comment: By distro I mean the distro I used, Ubuntu,Xubuntu,Kubuntu,etc...

Comment: Well, if you don't have any file in your drive to preserve, keep going to installing it. Use default partitioning, not encryption or Logical Volume Management (LVM). You may also disable secure boot option since you can always turn it back on without any issues, just to be sure that you can see your install for the first time.

If that fails again, please note precisely what you came across, what the error was so you can get the proper help.